# Jquery AJAX doesn't call a code behind method

Tags: asp.net, jquery, webforms, dotnetnuke

I am trying to invoke method from code behind via jquery.ajax... but nothing happens, no error's just methood is not invoked.
Maybe important to note I use DotNetNuke.
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

```
    jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
        if (jQuery(window).scrollTop() == jQuery(document).height() - jQuery(window).height()) {
            InfiniteScroll();
        }
    });

function InfiniteScroll() {
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "LoadItemsHandler.aspx/GetData",
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                if (data != "") {
                    alert('comething happened! :)');                    
                }
            }
        })
    };
```

I have tried to add handler method to ***.ascx*** and **.aspx** but none works:

```
[WebMethod]
        public static string GetData()
        {
            return "<div><h2>I am comming in peace from code behind.</h2><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ... :)</p></div>";
...
```

I have tried to put `alert()` in `InfiniteScroll()` and it's invoked on scrolling, but background method... nothing :(

**UPDATE 1**

```
public string Test(string input)
{
    var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    return serializer.Serialize(new { Name = input });
}
public static string GetData()
        {
            string json = Test("Mike");
            return json;
}
```

And I get:

```
Error:SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character
```

**UPDATE 2**
**Ok I got it**.
From code behind I return:

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            return serializer.Serialize(new { NewTotal = "777", OfType = "love" });
```

On the ajax call success I have:

```
success: function (data) {
                if (data != "") {
                    alert(data.d);
...
```

Now this present following data:

```
{"NewTotal":"777", "OfType":"love"}
```

And now the only issue I have is how to get `NewTotal` or `OfType` value because when I use `data.NewTotal` I get `undefined`?

Comment: what you see in firebug?

Comment: When I scroll firebug show this:
`POST http://dnn7site/Demos/LoadItemsHandler.aspx/GetData 200 OK 329ms`.

Comment: And I have added error log no and I get: `Error:SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character`

Comment: what version of jQuery?

Comment: 1.9.1 when I change DataType to HTML it returns whole page. It seams that I must somehow return JSon... from *.aspx

Comment: I have updated question with my try to return json from method.

Comment: Can you check my update 2 in question. I solved issue just don't know how to read specific data :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to convert result to JSON, it is auto. serialized to JSON

```
 [WebMethod()]
    public static object GetData()
    {
        return (new { NewTotal = "777", OfType = "love" });
    }
```

On JS, refer to newTotal like this

```
data.d.NewTotal
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all, calling Page methods inside UserControl will not work, so they should be defined in the aspx page.

Secondly, check for errors in firebug.

Also, make sure that you are calling from the same page.

Thirdly, use a webservice (*.asmx)

Comment: Why should I use web service (asmx) when I can use aspx? What is the benefit?

Comment: The benefit is that a .aspx is for rendering Web pages, HTML/CSS/Javascript is what a request to a .aspx standardly responds to client with.

A web service serves to respond with data to a client, in the XML or JSON form normally. It is not common or best practice to use an aspx code behind page to expose a public web method to call. That is what a web service is for. It is so easy to setup and bot the Web Service and the .ASPX can use the exact same logic by putting it in a method

Answer (score 0):

can use library `using Newtonsoft.Json;`

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Request["paramater"])
```